# ModelSim simulation won't advance

Tags: vhdl, simulation, modelsim

I am trying to simulate a testbench on ModelSim, but when I run the simulation, it never advances in time. The delta does not increase, either.

Are there any useful tips for debugging in a situation like this? I suspect that the problem may not be in my testbench, but in the `maze_solver` entity itself. Here are some possible problems:

- `maze_solver` also contains a structural description for another entity within it. Is it okay to simulate like this? As long as I have added that other entity into the ModelSim project?
- Could it be a problem with my sensitivity lists? I have checked them all, and all the right-hand side signals have been included on the sensitivity lists.
- Could it be a problem with my testbench? I have included the testbench code below.

Since the `maze_solver` design is long, I have not included it, but I can include it if necessary. It is a finite state machine (uses only case and if statements).

Below is my testbench:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity solver_testbench is
end entity solver_testbench;

architecture tb of solver_testbench is
signal clk,reset: STD_LOGIC;
signal cell_data: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
signal data_rdy: STD_LOGIC;
signal rd, wr: STD_LOGIC;
signal row, column: integer;
component maze_solver is
    generic(maze_width : in integer);
    Port (clk, reset : in STD_LOGIC;
        start : in STD_LOGIC;
        rd_cell_data : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
        data_rdy: in STD_LOGIC;
        rd,wr: out STD_LOGIC;
        row, column: out integer
        );
end component maze_solver;
begin

aravindans_maze_solver: maze_solver
    generic map(maze_width=>2)
    port map(clk=>clk, reset=>reset, start=>'1',rd_cell_data=>cell_data, data_rdy=>data_rdy, rd=>rd, wr=>wr,
         row=>row, column=>column);
process
begin
clk <= '1';
wait for 10 ns;
clk <= '0';
wait for 10 ns;
end process;

process
begin
cell_data <= (others=>'0');
if rd = '1' then
    if row = 0 and column = 0 then
        cell_data <= "01000000";
        data_rdy <= '1';
        wait for 20 ns;
        data_rdy <= '0';
    elsif row = 0 and column = 1 then
        cell_data <= "00010000";
        data_rdy <= '1';
        wait for 20 ns;
        data_rdy <= '0';
    elsif row = 1 and column = 0 then
        cell_data <= "00000000";
        data_rdy <= '1';
        wait for 20 ns;
        data_rdy <= '0';
    elsif row = 1 and column = 1 then
        cell_data <= "00000000";
        data_rdy <= '1';
        wait for 20 ns;
        data_rdy <= '0';
    end if;
else
    cell_data <= (others => '0');
    data_rdy <= '0';
end if;
end process;

reset <= '0', '1' after 5 ns;
end architecture tb;
```

Comment: If the delta count isn't increasing, it isn't a conventional combinational loop (which would timeout when the limit on deltas was exceeded). Look for loops within any processes, such as while loops, which may accidentally be infinite loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming maze_solver is bound, you are not getting some combination of rd, row and column values that cause execution of a wait statement in the second process.

Simulation time doesn't advance while any process is executing removing any possibility of getting any further combination of values leading to a wait statement. A deadlock. The process reaches it's last sequential statement and starts over at it's first without suspending.

It'd be possible to re-write this process driven by a clock event and depending on internal state.

Add a wait statement that will always be reached:

```
process
begin
cell_data <= (others=>'0');
if rd = '1' then
    if row = 0 and column = 0 then
        cell_data <= "01000000";
        data_rdy <= '1';
        wait for 20 ns;
        data_rdy <= '0';
    elsif row = 0 and column = 1 then
        cell_data <= "00010000";
        data_rdy <= '1';
        wait for 20 ns;
        data_rdy <= '0';
    elsif row = 1 and column = 0 then
        cell_data <= "00000000";
        data_rdy <= '1';
        wait for 20 ns;
        data_rdy <= '0';
    elsif row = 1 and column = 1 then
        cell_data <= "00000000";
        data_rdy <= '1';
        wait for 20 ns;
        data_rdy <= '0';
    end if;
else
    cell_data <= (others => '0');
    data_rdy <= '0';
end if;
wait for 20 ns;  -- ADDED WAIT 
end process;
```

You may have to tinker a bit once you get simulation time advancing.